# Case preserving find/replace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins

There seems to be no built-in support for case preserving find/replace in VisualStudio (see also a respective [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/case-preserving-search-replace/580810)).

What I mean is: searching for 'BadJob' and replacing with 'GoodJob' would do the following replacements

```
'badjob' -> 'goodjob'  
'BadJob' -> 'GoodJob'  
'badJob' -> 'goodJob'  
'BADJOB' -> 'GOODJOB'
```

So I am looking for a macro/add-in which implements case preserving find/replace. And if none exists, what is a good starting point to write my own (preferably based on the built-in find/replace capabilities).

Update:
I know I can make 4 manual replacements doing the job, but I am looking for a way to do it automatically in VS (like e.g. Emacs does it).
A common scenario: a variable named 'foo' and some functions DoFoo(), GetFoo(), ... and some additional comments containing 'foo' 'Foo' etc.
Now rename 'foo' to bar' yielding variable 'bar', functions DoBar(), GetBar() etc. by ONE find/replace.

Comment: I also want this. Would this be easy to do via a VS plugin?

Comment: Here is the new link to upvote for the feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Comment: And it's being implemented! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/keep-your-casing-with-case-preserving-find-and-replace/

Comment: nice to see this finally implemented, had suggested such a thing many-many years ago (guess all our older feedback was lost when MS transitoned to newer feedback mechanisms - hope they've settled now to a for-ever feedback mechanism)

Answer (score 12):

It's **not possible** in Visual Studio at the moment.

You can vote for this feature:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

I usually end up opening Sublime Text, Copy & Paste the code there, perform the case-preserving replacements there and Copy & Paste back to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

**It is now possible to do case-preserving find and replace**, albeit only for all upper case, all lower case, or title case (so it won't work on your specific examples).

Details can be [found here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_preserve-case-in-find-and-replace) (copied below):

> ## Preserve case in Find and Replace
>
> You can now preserve case when doing replacement in the editor's Find widget. The feature is turned on when the Preserve Case option (AB button) is turned on in the editor's Replace input box.
>
> [image: button]
>
> Currently VS Code only supports preserve **Full Upper Case**, **Full Lower Case**, and **Title Case**.
>
> [image: example]

Comment: Upvote the feature request for Visual Studio here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't even notice question was about visual studio and not code.

Comment: This is great, wonder why Visual Studio doesn't have when VS Code already has it!

Comment: I feel like Visual Studio may be phased out in the future, replaced by VS Code.

Comment: Visual Studio now has Preserve Case.

Answer (score 5):

Introduced in Visual Studio 2022 [17.8 preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-8-preview-1-has-arrived/#case-preserving-find-and-replace) as of August 9th, 2023.
[image: Demo of the Quick Find and Replace option]

[[image: Close up of the option with focus ring3]
[image: Option in the real deal Find and Replace]

Comment: It even references this question in the blog post announcing it https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/keep-your-casing-with-case-preserving-find-and-replace/

Comment: That may have been how I came to this question. I wanted to ensure everyone that was interested got the notice.

Answer (score 2):

open up the find options when you do the find/replace. check the case-sensitive option. you will have to do the flavours manually unless you do something like: http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/03/28/visual-studio-find-and-replace-regular-expressions/, or use something like: http://www.download3k.com/MP3-Audio-Video/Utilities-Plug-Ins/Download-Find-Replace.html

Comment: Doing 4 manual case-sensitive replacements is exactly what I NOT want to do. I am looking for a 'smart' find/replace in VS which does it this automatically (Emacs e.g. does that).

Comment: Upvote the new feature link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've coped with(out) it:

Open the file in Notepad++, and run a python script that does a case-keeping replace (like we used to be able to do with Visual Studio macros ... ah, the loss)

Install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
Install [npp python script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/download.shtml)
Make a new script thus:

```
from Npp import *

#Use capitalizeFirst because .capitalize will make the remaining string lower, but in CamelCase examples 
#we will want to preserve the user-typed casing. e.g. YourMonkeyMagic -> MyMonkieMagik 
def capitalizeFirst(str):
    return '%s%s' % (str[:1].upper(), str[1:])

#***  Ask user what to find and replace ***
find_str=notepad.prompt(notepad, 'Find (keeping case)', '')
replace_str=notepad.prompt(notepad, 'Replace (keeping case)', '')

#*** Do a case-sensitive replacement on each type ***
editor.replace(find_str.upper(), replace_str.upper())
editor.replace(find_str.lower(), replace_str.lower())
editor.replace(capitalizeFirst(find_str), capitalizeFirst(replace_str))
editor.replace(find_str, replace_str)
```

Comment: Upvote the feature request for Visual Studio here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Answer (score -2):

I know this doesn't answer your question exactly as you asked it, but for renaming variables and method names you can avoid the whole problem by right clicking on the identifier and using the rename option on the shortcut menu. That will update any references to that variable or method name.

Caveats: 
It only works in the scope of the current solution. 
It only updates references in managed code. 
It won't update literal strings such as "badcode" 
It won't update your comments.

This is one of my favorite features in VS2005/2008.

Comment: This only applies if you are using a .NET language and is not actually a feature if you are using C++.

Comment: You can upvote the case preservation feature request for Visual Studio here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html