# Case preserving substitute in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367052/case-preserving-find-replace-in-visual-studio) can be done in Vim?

> What I mean is: searching for 'BadJob'
>   and replacing with 'GoodJob' would do
>   the following replacements
>
> ```
> 'badjob' -> 'goodjob'  
> 'BadJob' -> 'GoodJob'  
> 'badJob' -> 'goodJob'  
> 'BADJOB' -> 'GOODJOB'
> ```

Comment: This should be a vim feature. It makes so much sense.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Use [abolish.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish):

```
:%S/badjob/goodjob/g
```

Comment: We do not deserve Tim Pope.

Comment: This plugin doesn't seem to work for me. If I a word like `BadJob` and I want to replace it with `GoodJob`, I can't use `%S/badjob/goodjob/g`. It fails to detect a match.

Comment: @Roymunson What you need to do is this: `%S/BadJob/GoodJob/g`, then the Subvert command will switch to mixed-case mode and will do all the substitions as given by OP.

Comment: @shivams Does the presence of mixed case anywhere in the arguments to `%S` activate mixed-case mode, or does the input argument `BadJob` need to literally match the thing you're trying to replace? The former seems like strange ux, and the latter seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: With this answer, how would abolish know to capitalise the 'J' in `GoodJob`? I would imagine at the very least one needs `%S/BadJob/GoodJob/g`

Comment: for me when i run this, it just opens a new copy of the current file as if i have typed `:sp` and it opens it on top only a few lines high.  wierd..

Answer (score 29):

I don't know if this is the kind of solution you're looking for... but i've used this:
[keepcase.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6)

There's no support otherwise in vim...

Answer (score 13):

sure u can

`:s/\cbad/\= strpart(submatch(0), 0 ,1) == toupper(strpart(submatch(0), 0, 1)) ? "GOOD" : "good"/`

ps. i'm guessing keepcase.vim encapsulates some similar logic :)

Comment: Yes it does since 2007: :%SubstituteCase/\cbadjob/GoodJob/g ^^

Comment: Meaning since gVim 7.2? I tried it in gVim 7.1 (12-May-2007) and it din't work :(

Comment: No, I've added the :SubstituteCase command to the plugin in 2007. That's all. The plugin is available on vim.org, and it is not shipped with vim as usual with with most plugins.

Comment: 1. This fails when the user has `:set ignorecase`.  2. `Bad` will be substituted by `GOOD` instead of `Good`.  3. The "`job`" part of the question is ignored, so this will also replace `lambada` → `lamgooda`.  Fixes and explanations for these bugs and a few other things in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782511/case-preserving-substitute-in-vim/30684545#30684545).  (Also LOLOWLs!)

Answer (score 10):

What about

```
:%s/\Cbadjob/goodjob/
:%s/\CBadJob/GoodJob/
:%s/\CbadJob/goodJob/  
:%s/\CBADJOB/GOODJOB/
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287449/5599687

Answer (score 9):

For most (non-complex) cases, i recommend @rampion’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782511/case-preserving-substitute-in-vim#49052078) over mine.
If you got a minute, my post might be still be worthwhile, though.  Level up your awareness for scripting gotchas.

---

---

You can just paste and adapt this:
<sub>(Of course, if you do this from time to time, you will want a plugin instead of this monstrosity.  But for some who are in a hurry and only need it once, this is a quick hack for your pasting pleasure:)</sub>

`:%s/\cbad\zejob/= ( submatch(0)[0] is# toupper(submatch(0)[0]) ? 'G' : 'g' ) . ( submatch(0)[1] is# toupper(submatch(0)[1]) ? 'OOD' : 'ood' )`

Apart from the search pattern, you have to edit the four `'`strings`'` in the replacement code: Edit the parts in **bold**:

> :%s/\c**bad**\ze**job**/= 
> ( submatch(0)[0] is# toupper(submatch(0)[0]) ? '**G**' : '**g**' ) . 
> ( submatch(0)[1] is# toupper(submatch(0)[1]) ? '**OOD**' : '**ood**' )

*Don't use this 'orange' version for pasting, since its linebreak characters will also break the command.*

[`/\ze`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cze) is vim regex syntactic sugar for marking a positive lookahead:  The pattern after `\ze` is checked for, but not substituted.

*`is#`*??  Let me explain…  (If interested.)

`#` (also in `==#` and [others](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-is)) enforces case sensitivity.  Otherwise, with `:set ignorecase` (which I use, because that is required for the useful [`:set smartcase`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartcase%27)), vim will consider `'a' == 'A'`!!
[image] [image] [image]
Crazy as it is, we really should account for it:  Because it is user-settings-dependent, **`==` should NEVAR be used!**  (Except where that would actually be what you want.)  I will even follow the recommendation to use `==#` when comparing integers: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/22.html#code-defensively

[`is#`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#E694) instead of `==#` is another way of coding defensively:  It improves type safety:  http://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml?showone=Type_checking#Type_checking
It should be used when comparing against a string literal.

`'single-quoted'` instead of `"double quoted"` [strings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-string) are another good practice: http://google.github.io/styleguide/vimscriptguide.xml?showone=Strings#Strings

<sub>HT @fc. - this answer builds on their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782511/case-preserving-substitute-in-vim/782617#782617), fixing a few shortcomings.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

If you're only matching an exact (case-independent) string with a few possible capitalizations, another possibility is:

```
:s/abc/\={'abc':'xyz','Abc':'Xyz'}[submatch(0)]/i
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the *keepcase* plugin is [SmartCase - replacing words while keeping original case](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1359). (Don't let yourself be discourage by the bad ratings.)

Comment: Is there a trick to shorten those hard to remember and tedious to type commands like `:%s/file\A\?size/\=SmartCase("LastModifiedTime")/ig`?

Comment: @MichaelHärtl: You can use the `:SmartCase` command. I've extended that [in my own fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SmartCase). Note that this requires [ingo-library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

All the problem is you have set: ignorecase in your .vimrc probably

You can program Vim to do sensitive/insensitive operation during both search and replace!

```
"Ctrl-h activating:
nnoremap <ctrl-h>  <Esc>:set noignorecase<CR><CR>:s%//<Right><Right><Right>

" Insensitive:
inoremap / <Esc>:set ignorecase<CR><CR>/<Right>
nnoremap / <Esc>:set ignorecase<CR><CR>/<Right>

" Case SENSITIVE search: (using key \ to search):
nnoremap \ <Esc>:set noignorecase<CR><CR>/<Right>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do this:

First declare some variables containing cases and replacements:

`let a = ['badjob', 'BadJob', 'badJob', 'BADJOB']`

`let b = ['goodjob', 'GoodJob', 'goodJob', 'GOODJOB']`

Second, apply a for loop as follow:

`for i in range(0,3) | exec '%s/' . a[i] . '/' . b[i] . '/g' | endfor`

Note that range function starts at 0.

Best regards.