# VIM: How to preserve case for search and replace

Tags: regex, vim, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case preserving substitute in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782511/case-preserving-substitute-in-vim)

Is it possible to do a search and replace in vim that preserves the case of the search term? This was a useful feature in intelliJ that I miss.

For instance, something like:

```
:s/[uU]ser/[pP]erson/ (obviously, this doesn't work)
```

Such that:

```
user->person
User->Person
```

Another example with multiple characters to preserve:

```
:s/[mM]y[uU]ser/[tT]his[pP]erson/g
```

Such that:

```
myuser->thisperson
myUser->thisPerson
MyUser->ThisPerson
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few approaches that can be taken.  If you want to stick with basic Vim functionality, you can do something like

```
:%s/[uU]ser/\=submatch(0) ==# 'user' ? 'person' : 'Person'/g
```

If you have Vim built with Perl bindings, you can make use of `:perldo`.  Depending on the length of the matching/replacing words and where the case you want to preserve is, this may or may not work.

```
:perldo s/(user)/"\L$1" ^ $1 ^ 'person'/ieg
```

Or you can make use of one of the [various](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1359) [scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6) that implement such functionality.

Comment: SmartCase looks like what I want

Comment: This answer has helped me doubly.  I used keepcase for case-preserving searches.  I came back to your answer to figure out how to do search and replace with varied pluralization spellings (group/groups => body/bodies).

Answer (score 2):

Redone the answer after giving it some thought ;-)

```
:s@\([Uu]\)ser@\=((submatch(1)=="U")?"P":"p")."erson"@gc
```

Of course it can be improved, but the idea stays.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for vim: [keepcase.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6)

Comment: This is close, but I've updated the question with another example with CamelCase replacement that this plugin doesn't seem to be able to handle, unless I'm mistaken.

The first example works like :SubstituteCase#\cuser#person#g