# How to do case insensitive search in Vim

Tags: search, vim, case-insensitive

I'd like to search for an upper case word, for example COPYRIGHT in a file. I tried performing a search like:

```
/copyright/i    # Doesn't work
```

but it doesn't work.  I know that in Perl, if I give the `i` flag into a regex it will turn the regex into a case-insensitive regex. It seems that Vim  has its own way to indicate a case-insensitive regex.

Answer (score 2641, accepted):

You can use the `\c` escape sequence anywhere in the pattern. For example:

`/\ccopyright` or `/copyright\c` or even `/copyri\cght`

To do the inverse (case *sensitive* matching), use `\C` (capital C) instead.

Comment: Also, `\c` can appear anywhere in the pattern, so if you type a pattern and then decide you wanted a case-insensitive search, just add a `\c` at the end.

Comment: I like to add `set ignorecase` for case-insensitive searching in my vimrc, and I can use `\C` to do a case-sensitive search similar to what @AlokSinghal mentioned.

Comment: There's also `set smartcase` which will automatically switch to a case-sensitive search if you use any capital letters.

Comment: Just want to add to Zaz's comment. `set smartcase` applies only when `set ignorecase` is already active. I was stumped on this for a while. See [Vim Tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Searching#Case_sensitivity).

Comment: Whut? Answer says: "Use `\c`. For the inverse, use `\c`." I think the "for the inverse" answer should state that a search for `/copyright` is case sensitive by default.

Comment: @coderMe,  It's the capitalization, `\c` versus `\C`

Comment: The comments in Zaz and VimTips should be incorporated in this answer.  Or should reference the other answer by Matthieu as it doesn't make much sense without it.

Answer (score 847):

As well as the suggestions for `\c` and `ignorecase`, I find the `smartcase` very useful.  If you search for something containing uppercase characters, it will do a case sensitive search; if you search for something purely lowercase, it will do a case insensitive search.  You can use `\c` and `\C` to override this:

```
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase
/copyright      " Case insensitive
/Copyright      " Case sensitive
/copyright\C    " Case sensitive
/Copyright\c    " Case insensitive
```

See:

```
:help /\c
:help /\C
:help 'smartcase'
```

Comment: The problem with `ignorecase` is that it affects substitutions as well as searches.  I find that it makes sense to have (smart) case-insensitive searches but case-sensitive substitutions by default.  But there's no way to do that that I know.

Comment: Worth noting that for `smartcase` to work, you also need `set ignorecase`. Great tip though, thanks!

Comment: I believe you could just use a \C in your search expression for substitutions, like this: `:%s/lowercasesearch\C/replaceString/g`.  This doesn't create the default functionality you desire, but it does allow you to force case-sensitivity for replacements while still benefiting from smartcase when searching.

Comment: You can also set the [`I` flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:s_flags) on a substitution to force the pattern to be case-sensitive. Like `:%s/lowercasesearch/replaceString/gI`.

Comment: Note from the help page (useful if you are "*" addicted like me): `After "*" and "#" you can make 'smartcase' used by doing a "/" command,
 recalling the search pattern from history and hitting <Enter>.
`

Comment: should add @Skilldrick 's comment to the answer in my opinion

Answer (score 364):

You can set the `ic` option in Vim before the search:

```
:set ic
```

To go back to case-sensitive searches use:

```
:set noic
```

`ic` is shorthand for `ignorecase`

Comment: also your only option if you're unlucky enough to still use Vi instead of Vim. `\c` doesn't work in vi.

Answer (score 72):

You can issue the command

```
:set ignorecase
```

and after that your searches will be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 62):

You can use in your `vimrc` those commands:

- `set ignorecase` - All your searches will be case insensitive
- `set smartcase` - Your search will be case sensitive if it contains an uppercase letter

You need to set `ignorecase` if you want to use what `smartcase` provides.

I wrote recently [an article about Vim search commands](http://web-techno.net/vim-search/) (both built in command and the best plugins to search efficiently).

Comment: It seems that `set smartcase` does not perform case insensitive searches if I do not use uppercase letters...is that normal?

Comment: Ok, just read below that you have to both set ignorecase and smartcase to have it work. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 51):

To switch between case sensitive and insensitive search I use this mapping in my .vimrc

`nmap <F9> :set ignorecase! ignorecase?`

Comment: Yes, but `ignorecase?` shows you the current state of the flag. (in the command line)

Comment: Thank you! To me, this is the most useful answer on the page: a way to quickly toggle between the two modes depending on what you're searching for at that exact moment.

Comment: Yes, it's better to have `ignorecase?` so you know the current state.

Comment: BTW, it's better to add `<Cr>` at the end, so the command is validated, and you don't have to hit the enter key (at least with neovim).

Answer (score 32):

By default, all searches in vi are case-sensitive. To do a case-insensitive search, go into command mode (press Escape), and type-
`:set ignorecase`
You can also type -
`:set ic`    as an abbreviation.

To change back to case-sensitive mode, type-
`:set noignorecase` or `:set noic`   in command mode

Comment: `:set ic!`

will toggle

Answer (score 29):

## The good old `vim[grep]` command..

```
:vimgrep /example\c/ &
```

- <kbd>\c</kbd> for case insensitive
- <kbd>\C</kbd> for case sensitive
- <kbd>%</kbd> is to search in the current buffer

---

[image]

Comment: `Cannot open file "&"`

Comment: I guess he they meant `%` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 27):

As others suggested:

```
:set ic
```

But the cool stuff is You can toggle such modes with:

```
:set ic!
```

Answer (score 21):

I prefer to use `\c` at the end of the search string:

```
/copyright\c
```

Answer (score 19):

put this command in your vimrc file

```
set ic
```

always do case insensitive search

Comment: I don't know why but my vim is set to case-insensitive by default, to counter this. use `set noic`.

Answer (score 10):

As @huyz mention sometimes desired behavior is using case-insensitive searches but case-sensitive substitutions. My solution for that:

```
nnoremap / /\c
nnoremap ? ?\c
```

With that always when you hit `/` or `?` it will add `\c` for case-insensitive search.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but does it prevent you from using the `smartcase` option?

Comment: Looks like it would since \c overrides `smartcase`

Answer (score 5):

Vim have 2 modes

1.edit mode

2. normal mode( Esc )

Search will work for normal mode

**/\c** for case sensitive

**/\c*search***

Comment: What about visual mode?

Answer (score 3):

You can set `ignorecase` by default, run this in shell

```
echo "set ic" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score -1):

## Note it is a difference where you place modifiers such as "\c" in your expresion:

> You can use the \c escape sequence anywhere in the pattern

Regardless from the accepted answers, which states that it is no difference of where to place modyfier in a regex pattern, its looks like it actually does matter.

example text:

```
asdasdasdasdasd wiktor asdasdasdasd   
adasdasdasd wiktor asdasda ahjkjlkhjkl
asdasd asd asdasdasdasd iuuuu -       
asdjkkkkkkkaopbsdasda                 
wiktor ----(---------------------)--
```

### Match

`\c^.*A?.*$`
`^\c.*A?.*$`
`^.*\cA?.*$`
`^.*A\c?.*$`

will output:
[image]

### No match

`^.\c*A?.*$`
`^.*A?\c.*$`
`^.*A?.\c*$`
`^.*A?.*$\c`

will output:
[image]
[image]

- `vim -version` VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jun  1 2020 06:42:35)
  Included patches: 1-869

Answer (score -2):

Some important information, if u want to find out more about the commands of vim, as mentioned below u can give a try the following steps :

- invoke the command "help" follow by a space and then complete the word with TAB key, once u find the right command press return key.

```
:help ignorecase
```

- information like the following will be displayed :

[image]

- you will be able to move forward and backward and also watch the short command, such as the case of "ignorecase" ( 'ic' ). In addition, another short example could be the case of 'smartcase' ('scs' and some more) :

[image]

- In order to leave of the documentation just type ":q" as usual and you will return to "command mode" .

```
:q
```

I really hope the information provided would be helpful for someone.

Best regards,