# VsVim - Case insensitive search by default

Tags: visual-studio, vim, visual-studio-2017, case-insensitive, vsvim

In Visual Studio 2017 with the VSVIM plugin, how do you set the default search to be case insensitive?

I found a question that answers it in general VIM, but I don't have a configuration file in a home directory to modify (because it is a plugin in Visual Studio): [How to do case insensitive search in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287440/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-in-vim)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, you can do case insensitive searches if you have

```
set ignorecase
```

on. And even more useful is additionally turning on

```
set smartcase
```

This will search case insensitive unless you put a capital letter or `\C` in your search, and then it will become case sensitive again.

> but I don't have a configuration file in a home directory to modify

That doesn't matter. Just create either a `.vimrc` or `.vsvimrc` in your home directory and add that line. VsVim will source both of those before launching.

It doesn't really matter which one you put it in, but I'd recommend putting in `.vimrc` since it'll affect both regular vim and VsVim. I use `.vimrc` for all regular settings and then vim plugins and advanced things, and I use `.vsvimrc` to fix things that break when being sourced in VsVim, since more advance vimscript and vim plugins don't work super well in it.

Comment: Oh really? I had no idea the plugin had access to the file system outside visual studio. Let me try that

Comment: Yup that worked beautifully. Visual studio even notified me that it's loading the `.vimrc` file. Cherio sir Cherio

Comment: `set smartcase` doesn't seem to work for me. `set ignorecase` does though.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023,
VSCode Vim search & replace is by default case-insensitive.

You could try using something like this, for Sensitive/Insensitive:

**Case-Sensitive**:

`:s/FOO\C/BAR/`

Add a `\C` to the Search phrase.

`\C : Is for 'Match Case'`

Above will only find, 'FOO' & replace with 'BAR'

**Case-Insensitive**:

`:s/FOO/BAR/`

Above will find, FOO/Foo/FoO/foo etc & replace with 'BAR'