# Force Case sensitive search in vim

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc` I have case-insensitive search turned how. However, rarely I'll search for something like "HEAD" (a git word) where I need it to be case-sensitive. Is there a flag that can be entered in the search so that I can temporarily override the search settings, something like:

```
/HEAD*case-sensitive
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive search in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287440/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-in-vim). Just put `\C` anywhere in your search string: `/\CHEAD` or `/HEAD\C`.

Comment: @lurker `\C` is case sensitive `\c` is case insensitive...

Comment: `set ignorecase` + `set smartcase` together will let you have case-sensitive search only when you use capital letters somewhere in your search

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo yes I know. If you read the question carefully, you'll see that's what the op wanted.

Comment: @lurker HEAD=>TABLE I am sorry!