# How to find and replace upper and lowercase and keep capitalization in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

Let's say I have:

```
foo and Foo
```

How can I find and replace it to

```
bar and Bar
```

With one regex/find and replace command in Vim? By default I have my Vim setup to find either uppercase and lowercase when searching. Now I just want to replace keeping the capitalization. Is this even possible?

Comment: See here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782511/case-preserving-substitute-in-vim

Answer (score 8):

I recommend Tim Pope's [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin. It provides the `:Subvert` or `:S` command for short that does exactly what you ask.

```
:%S/foo/bar/g
```

Drew Neil over at [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) has a nice screencast, [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you do `set ignorecase!` before and after your search. If you do case sensitive searching often then you can map this to something. If you do a lot with mixed cases and case matching you might want to look at plugins.