# Is there a way to copy the case of a character and impose it on some other character in output?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, replace

VS2008 allows you to use regular expressions in the find/replace dialogs.

I've run into a couple of moments where I've needed to copy the case of a specific character and impose it on the replace string.

For example I have a block of code that has Monday and monday scattered throughout.  I want to change each Monday to a Friday as well as each monday to a friday.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please upvote the Case Preservation Search & Replace feature request for Visual Studio at this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using the built-in Visual Studio Find and Replace window dialog.

[Case preserving find/replace in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367052/case-preserving-find-replace-in-visual-studio)

[find and replace preserving case sensitivity](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/344469/find-and-replace-preserving-case-sensitivity)

Comment: First link pretty much explains it all

Comment: First sentence explains it better than any of the links.

Comment: There really should exist something like this in the Find and Replace dialog. It's a time saver.

Comment: Please upvote this feature request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/580810/case-preserving-search-replace.html